# Hook for node preload

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

Is there any hook for when the `node_load` or `node_load_multiple` functions are called, but before they are actually loaded from the DB?

I need this because I want to cache my nodes before Drupal goes and queries the DB for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there's no such hook I'm afraid (see the list of [hooks for Drupal 7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7)).

If you want caching that goes beyond the normal static page cache provided by `node_load()` then you might want to look at the [Entity Cache](http://drupal.org/project/entitycache) module, which *"puts core entities into Drupal's cache API."*. Even if you don't end up using that module you can inspect the code to get some ideas for implementing your own caching system.

Comment: Thanks. Installed this module and it reduced my number of queries from ~160 to ~70. It's great, but too advanced for me to understand. Guess it's fine for now :)